# Breeze 1.4.8 Bug: Query MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges never notifies entityChanged or hasChanges

Tags: breeze

When I requery my only dirty entity with MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges, the manager says hasChanges is true, even though the entityState is unchanged. This is because the entityChanged & hasChangesChanged are never published.

Looking at the source in mergeEntity (line 14258) the intended code for this will never work as it is testing the entity state after it has been updated & its testing for the existance of the isUnchanged function not it's return value.

I think it should be something like

```
if (mergeStrategy === MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges
        || targetEntityState.isUnchanged()) {
    var isTargetEntityStateUnchanged = targetEntityState.isUnchanged();

    ...

    // this is needed to handle an overwrite of a modified entity with an unchanged entity 
    // which might in turn cause _hasChanges to change.
    if (!isSaving && !isTargetEntityStateUnchanged) {
        em._notifyStateChange(targetEntity, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to take a look later today ( or tomorrow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Breeze 1.4.9 (or later), available now, this has been fixed. and thanks for finding it.

Comment: Just looking at the 1.4.9 code now, I dont think this will fix it as the tested targetEntityState is an object reference and will always be Unchanged. That's why I used my var isTargetEntityStateUnchanged.

Comment: There were a number of other changes related to this, and I have a number of test cases that show this working correctly. Give me a failing test case ( ideally like on of the DocCode tests) and I'll look into it further.  Have you actually confirmed that your code still fails?

Comment: Finally got a chance to check this. My mistake - your fix is all good. Many thanks for the fix.